Integrating Google Authentication in a MERN stack application
I am beginner in MERN full stack Development. I was taught MERN by doing a project (they taught me how to build a stack overflow like website).
So in order to build on top of that, I was trying to integrate Google Authentication into my app. But I was confused about which package to use since you could do it in React or in Express/Node. I thought Authentication in backend would be the better choice. But I ran into a lot of problems. Because some of the packages were deprecated. And some of the tutorials use cookies-sessions and some use express-session.
So my question is, what authentication do you guys use and i need suggestions on some good tutorials or articles.
What I did was, when I click on the Google Auth button, it redirects the user to the backend url in which passport.js runs and does all the Authorization. But then I needed the user data and jwt token for the frontend. So I set up a url (/api/user/profile) which will be used to fetch the data (in an useEffect inside the App component). I get the data and set the CurrentUser state to the user data I got. But when I go to another page, my state is getting set to null.

What exactly you are asking?
If you are getting data in your react app from backend, and on switching to different page, your state is setting to null in frontend app, Isn't it a Frontend issue?
From your question's title it seemed like you are unable to implement Google Auth, Please be more clear.
